# Drawing a circle around a point in vue2-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I am using Vue to build a site that takes in some data and displays a google map with markers and circles around the points with the markers.

So far I can create the map with markers perfectly fine, however I have no idea what the proper way to create a circle is with the Vue2-google-maps package, despite having combed through the Documentation for a long time.

Here is the code so far

```
    <GmapMap
      :center="center"
      :zoom="10"
      class="google-map">
        <GmapMarker
          :key="index"
          v-for="(pin, index) in markers"
          :position="pin.position"
          :icon="pin.icon"
          :clickable="true"
          :draggable="true"
          @click="center=pin.position">
        </GmapMarker>
        <GmapCircle
          :key="index"
          v-for="(pin, index) in markers"
          :center="pin.position"
          :radius="1000"
          :visible="true"
          :fillColor="red"
          :fillOpacity:="1.0">
        </GmapCircle>
    </GmapMap>
```

Note that markers is a list of markers that is created somewhere else in the code.

If you take out the  tags, the code works perfectly fine placing all the markers. I just need to know what the proper tag/object set is for creating a circle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the right track, [`GmapCircle`](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/src/components/circle.js) component in `vue2-google-maps` library is intended for creating circles on the map. There are might be several reasons why circles are not getting displayed:

- `center` property value is *invalid*, the supported format is `{lat: <lat>, lng: <lng>}` or [`google.maps.LatLng` value](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng)
- maybe you could not spot them due to relatively small size (given the provided `2` kilometer diameter, they could be easily missed)?

Regarding `fillColor` and `fillOpacity` properties, they need to be passed via `options` property, e.g. `:options="{fillColor:'red',fillOpacity:1.0}"`

Anyway the following example demonstrates how to create circles on map via `vue2-google-maps`

```
<GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="zoom" ref="map">
  <GmapCircle
    v-for="(pin, index) in markers"
    :key="index"
    :center="pin.position"
    :radius="100000"
    :visible="true"
    :options="{fillColor:'red',fillOpacity:1.0}"
  ></GmapCircle>
</GmapMap>



export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 5,
      center: { lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 },
      markers: [
        { Id: 1, name: "Oslo", position: { lat: 59.923043, lng: 10.752839 } },
        { Id: 2, name: "Stockholm", position: { lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 } },
        { Id: 3,  name: "Copenhagen", position: { lat: 55.675507, lng: 12.574227 }},
        { Id: 4, name: "Berlin", position: { lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 } },
        { Id: 5, name: "Paris", position: { lat: 48.856127, lng: 2.346525 } }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i had error that saw:" GmapCircle not define component", so i have used this code:

```
<gmap-circle
                    v-for="(infoWindow, index) in arrayMarkers"
                     :key="'circle_'+index"
                     radius="100"
                    :center="infoWindow.position"
 
                />
```